# Communicating with bash scripts from python

Tags: python, windows, bash, mingw

I am running some shell test scripts from a python script under Windows. The shell scripts are testing the functionality of various modules.

The problem that I faced is that some scripts can hang. For this I added a timeout for each script. This timeout has a default value. But this timeout value can be changed by the bash script - from a bash function ( SetMaxTime ) - I can modify SetMaxTime.

When the default value is used I wait for that period of time in python and if the bash script is not done I will consider that test as failed due to timeout.

The problem is when the default value of timeout is changed from bash. Is there a way to communicate with a bash script (ran with mingw) from python?

NOTE: The scripts are ran under Windows.

Comment: Your question is too generic to answer.  Show us your code, explain what you think may be wrong with it, and we'll respond with fixes.

Comment: I have given a generic answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can communicate between them, just read/write from a file or pair of files (one for Python to write to and the bash script to read from, and the other for the visa-versa situation).

Comment: I thought that there were better ways to do it. But since it is not a time critical task I can use files.

Comment: I agree, this is a horrible way to do it, but as a quick and dirty solution it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Have your script output information on stdout when it sets the timeout value.  eg. When the timeout changes, the script could output:

```
TIMEOUT_SECONDS=2
```

In your Python code that invokes the script, look for this marker in the output of the invoked script and adjust the test timeout accordingly.

For this, you'll probably want to invoke your script using the the [subprocess.Popen](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects) method, specifying the `PIPE` option for stdout.  You'll then need to read the subprocess [stdout](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdout) attribute while the test is running, looking for the `TIMEOUT_SECONDS=xxx` output from your script and adjust the timeout period.